# use mysql dayname as a column name

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to use dayname output as a columname

currently I am using this

```
SELECT *,
LEFT(thu,5) as open1
FROM ...
WHERE ...
```

but I would like to replace the thu string with a dynamic current day(3 letters) and still use it as a column name.

Comment: Could you give a couple examples of desired output? It's unclear from your quest whether you want the "dynamic current day" to be (a) the column input value, or (b) the column result value, or (c) the column name, or (d) some combination of these. Please give sample output for two different days.

Comment: so i wanna use LCASE(LEFT(DAYNAME(NOW()),3)) instead of 'thu' as the column name simple as that

Comment: help us first by creating a sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/ left side  the create and insert querys.   push button "Build schema". the browser URL should change and post us that here, when we have example data so we maybe can figure out what you do mean...

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f422/1  so i want to compare the current time with thu & thu2 see if the store is open...

Comment: OK, I thought so. That requires dynamic SQL in a procedure, which mat be more trouble than it's worth. More information [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Comment: @Ed Gibbs: dynamic SQL is a lot more trouble than its worth, given that there are only seven possibilities for day of week.

Comment: @kangaroo: what you want to do can't be done. All identifiers, including column references, in a SQL statement are static. They cannot be modified while the statement executes. As I indicated in my answer, you could dynamically generate the statement (as a separate step), and then execute it, or you could dynamically choose from a set of statements, or you can use a static statement that includes conditional test to determine which column it returns values from.

Comment: @Spencer7593 - I was answering the OP's comment that ended in "... simple as that" (which I think qualifies as irony). I agree that dynamic SQL is more trouble than it's worth, especially since it'll complicate the client end by forcing it to deal with seven shifting column names. But that's based on my understanding of the question, and I'm still not 100% sure I understand it; the fiddle unfortunately didn't help.

Comment: ok, maybe i will send the day data from front end to the backend

Comment: @Ed: I agree, what he's asking is very unclear. But what he wants to do is modify the expression in the SELECT list dynamically, based on the current day of the week. When that statement runs on a Friday, he wants it to return the leftmost 5 positions of the column named `fri`. (When I say "simple as that", doesn't it make it that simple?)

Comment: That's kinda like I saw it, and as I look over my comment it sounds catty. @kangoroo - when I said "simple as that" was ironic I was referring to the fact that it's horribly complicated in SQL. I think your best option is to keep calling the column `open1` or whatever works for you, and then deal with labeling it in the front end. You can get a variable column name with dynamic SQL but it flat out isn't worth the trouble.

Comment: i understand him he wants to query to see if a time is between the periode to see if a store is open or not un a day, but really kangoroo if you want to fix this problem you really should think over your table design should be more normalized then you dont need querys like these.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, it can't be done. Column references (like all identifiers) in a SQL statement are static. Identifiers can't be replaced with expressions that are determined at runtime.

---

The longer answer is that you would either need to dynamically generate the statement, or to choose one of a set of possible statements to execute, based on whatever conditions.

A third approach might get you what you want, by referencing all the possible column names you would want to select from, and making the return from that column conditional based on the day of the week.

Something like this achieves the same result:

```
SELECT LEFT(CASE DAYNAME(NOW())
            WHEN 'Sunday'    THEN t.sun
            WHEN 'Monday'    THEN t.mon
            WHEN 'Tuesday'   THEN t.tue
            WHEN 'Wednesday' THEN t.wed
            WHEN 'Thursday'  THEN t.thu
            WHEN 'Friday'    THEN t.fri
            WHEN 'Saturday'  THEN t.sat
            END,5) AS open1
  FROM t
```

(To avoid issues with different settings for day of the week names, based on language/region, I'd prefer to use the `DAYOFWEEK` function instead. And I'd be more likely to repeat the `LEFT` function, even if it is repeated, it seems easier to read:

```
SELECT CASE DAYOFWEEK(NOW())
         WHEN 1 THEN LEFT(t.sun,5)
         WHEN 2 THEN LEFT(t.mon,5)
         WHEN 3 THEN LEFT(t.tue,5)
         WHEN 4 THEN LEFT(t.wed,5)
         WHEN 5 THEN LEFT(t.thu,5)
         WHEN 6 THEN LEFT(t.fri,5)
         WHEN 7 THEN LEFT(t.sat,5)
       END AS open1
  FROM t
```

Comment: this is not what i am looking for buddy, sorry

Comment: @kangaroo: then the short answer is the right one. what you are looking for *can't* be done in a single SQL statement. sorry.